# Animation Nodes - How to make text creep up?

Tags: animation-nodes

This is for future projects with motion graphics. I wish to mimic below with Animation Nodes. 
Assistance appreciated. Thanks in advance. 
.

[image]

This below example with little more bounce than the former.

[image]

Comment: You can try to separate each character in different objects and after use the frametime node + math node to define the Z-axis size.

Comment: I would have done that, but it becomes laborious to work with long sentences or paragraphs. So, that is why I need to learn Animation Nodes in order to speed up labour. Thank you for suggestions, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offset the scale of characters based on an inverse delay falloff as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

The little bounce can be achieved by changing the delay interpolation into a back one:

[image: Bounce]

Comment: Wonderful. Greatly appreciated. Thank you very much. You are a great help. =)

Comment: For everybody, here's a project file (Blender 2.8 Beta + Animation Nodes 2.1.4) with that setup : https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6046/